# Using jQuery to add text of each dropdown option as its value

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery load() function to load an HTML file containing a multiple select menu

```
<select multiple>
<optgroup label="optgroup1">   
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

(there are further optgroups and options in the real code)

In the callback I would like to add a value to each `<option>` which equals the value of the text, so the final HTML would be:

```
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
```

The closest I have managed is

```
$("option").each(function() {
    $("option").attr('value', $(this).text());
});
```

Unfortunately, when I inspect the code I see that this is adding the text from the last option to each value:

```
<option value="A">C</option>
<option value="B">C</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
```

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("option").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).text());
});
```